# getFromFirebase.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Trying to sync my firebase store with my redux store because obviously I want them to align as much as possible, but I'm getting tied up with promises.

I thought you declare a function and return a promise and then when you call that function, you can call `.then()` on it?

so here I am defining my function (which returns a promise):

```
const getFromFirebase = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/users/').once('value', resolve)
  })
};
```

I then call it with `.then()` on it

```
export default getFromFirebase.then(store => {
  return createStore(reducers, store.data, enhancer);
});
```

but I get the error: `getFromFirebase.then is not a function`

what have I done wrong/misunderstood?

Comment: `getFromFirebase()` instead of `getFromFirebase`.

Comment: ah, yes. functions 101, literally the first thing ever learnt when learning how to code :D